# Extract certificate (.cer) from installer programmatically

Tags: powershell, certificate, installation, digital-signature, x509certificate

I am building an installer and need to extract the .cer so that it can be added to trusted publisher, similar to this question/answer.

https://superuser.com/a/464233

I've managed to do that and everything works fine. Can the "Copy to file" from within Digital Signatures tab be automated using PowerShell or something similar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run `Get-AuthenticodeSignature` cmdlet to retrieve authenticode signing certificate from MSI.

Comment: C'mon, the returning object contains signing certificate. Pipe it to Format-List cmdlet and you will see.